# Accessing ModelState in AuthorizationHandler

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to access `ModelState` in AuthorazationHandler. Handler is triggered for `GET` action:

```
var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
httpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
var routeData = httpContext.GetRouteData();
var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, routeData, controllerActionDescriptor);
```

I see that `routeData` contains proper values, but `actionContext.ModelState` is empty. Why can this be?

Comment: My guess is because `ModelState` is part of MVC middleware, so it comes later in the pipeline.

Comment: But I create `ActionContext` manually, and it has `ModelState` property.

Comment: @Knelis is right here. The `ModelState` property is populated by the MVC pipeline, but the authz handler runs before that happens.